# Тождественны ли конструкции?

Tags: javascript

Тождественна ли конструкция:

```
if(typeof data !== 'undefined')
```

конструкции:

```
if(data)
```

И как лучше всего проверять, существует ли какая-то переменная?

Comment: нет. не тождественны. зачем вам проверять существование переменной?

Comment: `'data' in window`

Comment: @MikhailVaysman "переменная" - это грубо говоря. Например, я отправляю на бэкенд какой-то запрос, а мне возвращается ответ в теле `.done(function(response))`. Что в этом случае означает `if(response)`? Много раз видел такое, но интересно, что это значит.

Comment: --зачем вам проверять существование переменной? Например, на наличие элемента на странице.

Comment: такое может значить, что хотят проверить на **Truthy**

Comment: Я обычно так проверяю: `if( data !== 'undefined' )` :) А в общем, @Mikhail Vaysman прав

Comment: @Yuri при `data = undefined` вернёт true :)

Comment: @andreymal, ну так понятно, Вы же присваиваете переменной `undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не тождественны. 1 вариант исключает только ситуацию, когда переменная `undefined`. 2 вариант исключает так же `null`, `0`, пустую строку, `NaN`.

Comment: как же ты забыл про `false`